# Silly vector-related question

Tags: vectors

It's probably a silly question but, I don't understand this :

[image]

How can this be always true when

$\vec{v}.d\vec{v} = v.dv.cos(\alpha) = v.dv \Leftrightarrow \alpha = [2\pi]$

It seems contradictory...

Comment: As you note, $ \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{v} \ne v\mathrm{d}v $ in general. It is only true if they're parallel or antiparallel.

Comment: There are no silly questions, only silly places. Like Camelot.

Comment: That's what I thought but I found this in a demonstration of Euler's Equation (Hydrodynamics) and that would mean it's only true if velocity's direction doesn't change right ?

Answer (score 1):

The physical context of the text most likely specifies or implies that $\vec{v}$ and $d\vec{v}$ are collinear, i.e. the angle between them is $\alpha = 0$, thus $\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{v} = v \cdot dv \cdot \cos(0) = v \cdot dv$.

Comment: The context is the displacement of a volume element of fluid along a streamline. So I guess the proof is only true for straight streamline ?

Comment: Since this is a differential description at a distinct position (as opposed to a global description of the entire experiment): No, I´m pretty sure that $\vec{v}$ and $d\vec{v}$ being collinear does not force a straight streamline. But it must be continuous and differentiable for sure. Trajectory shape is something you'd inspect during DE-solving, integration and parametrization thereof, but not on the basis of a differential description.

Comment: How can the streamline be curved if all the small displacements follow the same direction ?